# jquery -changing css property and repeating

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, properties, delay

I have this sprite sheet http://codepen.io/benasl/pen/yabpxo that I want to be changed to another one after it ends, and after the second one ends the first one needs to start again, and so on... I managed to do this with just changing css properties, but now how do I make them loop?

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $(".kambarys2").css('display', 'block');
}, 3100);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #69e4c3;
}
.kambarys {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/pra08AS.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 380px;
  height: 372px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 40%;
  animation: convejor 3s steps(76) infinite;
}
@keyframes convejor {
  from {
    background-position: 0px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -28880px;
  }
}
.kambarys2 {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/TFvZvWz.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 380px;
  height: 372px;
  top: 108px;
  left: 40%;
  animation: convejor 3s steps(76) infinite;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="kambarys"></div>
<div class="kambarys2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- change the background image using an array:

```js
var cnt=0,images=["http://i.imgur.com/TFvZvWz.jpg","http://i.imgur.com/pra08AS.jpg"]
setInterval(function() {
  $(".kambarys").css({"background-image":"url("+images[cnt]+")"});
  cnt++;
  if (cnt>=images.length) cnt=0;
}, 3100);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #69e4c3;
}
.kambarys {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/pra08AS.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 380px;
  height: 372px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 40%;
  animation: convejor 3s steps(76) infinite;
}
@keyframes convejor {
  from {
    background-position: 0px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -28880px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="kambarys"></div>
```

- Toggle two divs

```js
var cnt=0;
setInterval(function() {
  $(".kambarys0").toggle(cnt);
  $(".kambarys1").toggle(!cnt); cnt=!cnt
}, 3100);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #69e4c3;
}
.kambarys0 {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/pra08AS.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 380px;
  height: 372px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 40%;
  animation: convejor 3s steps(76) infinite;
}
.kambarys1 {
  display:none;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/TFvZvWz.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  width: 380px;
  height: 372px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 40%;
  animation: convejor 3s steps(76) infinite;
}
@keyframes convejor {
  from {
    background-position: 0px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -28880px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="kambarys0"></div>
<div class="kambarys1"></div>
```

- Loop more than two divs

```js
var cnt = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    cnt++;  
    if (cnt >= $(".kambarys").length) cnt = 0;
    $(".kambarys").hide();
    $("#kambarys" + cnt).show();
  },
  3100);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #69e4c3;
}
.kambarys {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 380px;
  height: 372px;
  top: 100px;
  left: 40%;
  animation: convejor 3s steps(76) infinite;
}
#kambarys0 {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/pra08AS.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#kambarys1 {
  display: none;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/TFvZvWz.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#kambarys2 {
  display: none;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/F6bNA00.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


@keyframes convejor {
  from {
    background-position: 0px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -28880px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="kambarys" id="kambarys0"></div>
<div class="kambarys" id="kambarys1"></div>
<div class="kambarys" id="kambarys2"></div>
```

Comment: It works, however, when they change there is a slight blink and that is what i'm trying to avoid

Comment: Then have two and do 

`$(".kambarys0").toggle(cnt);$(".kambarys1").toggle(!cnt); cnt=!cnt`

Comment: I don't quite follow what to change

Comment: For me it blinks the first time and then it goes without blinking, however if i had more than two spritesheets? lets say 3 or 4? http://codepen.io/benasl/pen/yabpxo

Comment: Give them an ID and use the kambarys as class: `setInterval(function() {
  if (cnt>=$(".kambarys").length) cnt=0;
  $("#kambarys"+cnt).toggle();
  cnt++;
  $("#kambarys"+cnt).toggle(); 
}, 3100);`

Comment: Again, don't quite follow what to change..sorry for my stupidity

Comment: Thanks, you were very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

One answer would be that you have a function for this and this function would restart itself every X seconds.

Example:

```js
function startcounter() {
    $( "#foo" ).append( "<p>Test</p>" ); // do what you want
    setTimeout(startcounter, 3*1000); // 3*1000 = 3 Seconds.
}

setTimeout(startcounter, 3*1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo"><p>This is the div where the JS add every 3 Seconds a "Test".</p></div>
```

Comment: So i should type the time that i want it to restart in 'startcounter()'?

Comment: Somehow it doesn't loop